# Is installing an outlet inside a cabinet with LPG tank a good idea?

Tags: electrical, gas, stove

I am installing a new gas stove on my counter top, it is a gas stove that uses LPG but has an electric igniter that must be connected to the wall. The cabinet housing the LPG tank is directly below the gas stove. All I need now is to run an outlet inside the cabinet to connect to the stove, but the idea of an exposed outlet going to an enclosed spaced with a highly flammable source does not sit well with me.

How is this properly done? Because given how short the wire on the stove is and the included hose for the LPG tank it really does look like they want it to be in the same location, and I don't think a known brand (Whirlpool) would be that incompetent if that is a no no.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?  Also, is this a built-in unit or something that just sits atop the counter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it is kind of a built in thing. it fits on a hole on the counter top. I am replacing an old gas stove, so i could not really move it somehere else since the hole is already there. The best option i have now is to move the outlet to the cabinet beside it and just seal the tiny hole that i will drill. this also mean splicing the wire for it to be extended

Comment: Quite sure your local code will state how many feet the tank has to be away from any outlet or door/window.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel OP's profile does indicate Philippines. It is handy, though, if that's made explicit in the post body. (I was wondering where Tim got that from in his [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/223078/34147) and thought to click the OP's profile link.)

Comment: @FreeMan - it's a pet peeve of mine that often there are useful clues missing from profiles - 'this person prefers...'

Comment: Possibly, depending on code, A longer gas supply line could be purchased and the tank located in a separate space from the outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Not a clue in the Phillipines, but the wire can be lengthened to whatever you want, using a same sized wire - that only needs to have electricity for ignition.

The hole for the tubing - through what? Metal will need a grommet, wood needs just a hole, and the space for the bottle needs a bottom vent at least. I guess the regulator is on the bottle, so that could go outside, with a longer pipe through the wall (again, protected) if it's not going to be potentially stolen.

Comment: I would agree with a bottom vent if the tank was stored inside. The instructions on most LP gas tanks say not to store inside.

Comment: @EdBeal - in rural France, it's the norm. Cookers have a space for the gas bottle so it's very cclose to the cooker itself. And consider mobile gas heaters - the bottle is contained within.